# Translating boost (asio) error messages to natural language

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-asio

The `boost::system::error_code` has a conversion to string function that handily gives me something to print.  Unfortunately, it's typically something like "system:9", which isn't overly useful.  It appears, from reading source, that the numbers are established in enums, so I can test for specific conditions, but less easily know which condition has been encountered.

It appears that passing `error_condition.value()` to `perror()` / `strerror()` happens to work, but I've not found documentation that specs that this is guaranteed.  Did I miss this?  Should I be more suspicious?

I'm suspicious mostly because I don't understand why the string printed by `operator<<()` doesn't just use `strerror()` if that is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this in my projects to make error reporting more informative:

```
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>


struct report
{
    report(boost::system::error_code ec) : ec(ec) {}

    void operator()(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        os << ec.category().name() << " : " << ec.value() << " : " << ec.message();
    }

    boost::system::error_code ec;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, report rep)
    {
        rep(os);
        return os;
    }
};



int main()
{
    auto ec = boost::system::error_code(EINTR, boost::system::system_category());
    std::cout << "the error is : " << report(ec) << '\n';
}
```

example output:

```
the error is : system : 4 : Interrupted system call
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91c02689f2ca74b2

Comment: only noticed this now, note that the verbose generic serialization is close to what `error_code` and `system_error` already do. Also, it's not best practice to hard code a category. Instead I would rely on `make_error_code` to get the correct one: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8411c676e7a3a885 - that's less code and more safety. Of course you might still want the `report` "manipulator" if you're dealing with non-thrown error-codes. Unless, of course you do this: [8 lines of code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3feb628805dccaaf)

Answer (score 4):

You should probably just use `system::error_code::message()`:

```
void foo(boost::system::error_code ec) {
     std::cout << "foo called (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
}
```

The operator<< must work for all categories - which is open-ended by design, so that's why only the category name is displayed.